# using Ajax with Laravel give me status 500

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

i'm using ajax with laravel for the first time and i have an error, it gives me status 500 Internal Server Error back.. Im sending the token and everything seems to be ok, can you guys check and maybe see where the problem is :), thanks a lot.

Code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#ajaxSubmit').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            console.log(listvalues)

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('downloadSelectedCsv') }}",
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    ids: listvalues,
                },

            });
        });
    });
```

Route:  (Web.php)

Route::post('/download/csv', [\App\Http\Controllers\UrlController::class, 'downloadSelected'])->middleware(['auth'])->name('downloadSelectedCsv');

Comment: Please try to check your error logs let's see what you have. The log can be found in storage/logs/ then the Laravel log file.

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error is a generic error message informing you that the server crashed while processing the request. Beyond that, it's (intentionally) meaningless, and is of very little use for debugging. You need to check the error logs on the server to try and find the underlying exception message. Once you've got that, you stand a chance of identifying the problem.

Comment: Whats the contents of the `downloadSelected` method in the `\App\Http\Controllers\UrlController` class?

Comment: I found it guys, i'm an idiot, i had dd(); in my controller for debugging purposes and that was the problem.. like i said, i'm using ajax for the first time :D. Thanks a lot for your help and time. :)

Comment: Hit your route with a browser, http://localdev.local/download/csv   then step through your code to see where it's broken.